# ESG risk factors

Tags: risk, risk-models, esg

In the context of EU action on sustainable finance, the European Commission has initiated a series of regulations in order to achieve the goals of Paris Agreement on sustainability.
One of those regulations is the disclosure regulation, it compels investment managers to reveal more information regarding the sustainability of their business and products including risk sustainability.

I am wondering what are different risk factors related to sustainability? and market practice or methodology in calculating such factors?